# Hibernate Transaction Manager not committing data changes

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, h2

I'm using Hibernate 4 to write data to an H2 embedded in-memory database and there seems to be a problem with transactions. The application already uses Oracle and H2 has been added with a separate `DataSource`, `SessionFactory`, and `TransactionManager`. The original `TransactionManager` is marked as default and the H2 `TransactionManager` has the qualifier `memTransactions`

The following code - specifically the `load` function - correctly populates the `memEvents` variable at the end with the written data.

```
@Repository
@Transactional(transactionManager = "memTransactions")
public class EventMemDaoHibernate implements EventMemDao {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "memSessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory memSessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<EventMem> getEvents() {
        return memSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(EventMem.class).list();
    }

    @Override
    public void load(List<Event> allEvents) {
        Session session = memSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        for (Event e : allEvents) {
            EventMem memEvent = new EventMem(e);
            session.save(memEvent);
        }
        List<EventMem> memEvents = getEvents(); // correct
    }
}
```

However the following code produces an empty `memEvents` list

```
@Autowired
private EventMemDao eventMemDao;

List<Event> allEvents = eventDao.getAllEvents();
eventMemDao.load(allEvents);    // calls the load function shown above
List<EventMem> memEvents = eventMemDao.getEvents(); // empty
```

I assume this is related to transaction management (e.g.: data is not auto-committed after the call to `.save()`). However when I tried explicitly beginning and committing a transaction within `EventMemDaoHibernate#load`, I receive this error:

> nested transactions not supported

So, from what I can tell the `TransactionManager` is working.

My `TransactionManager` and related bean definitions are shown below.

```
<bean
    id="memTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="memSessionFactory" />
    <qualifier value="memTransactions"/>
</bean>

<bean id="hDataSource" class="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource">
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:scripts/init-h2.sql'" />
  <property name="user" value="sa" />
  <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
<bean
  id="memSessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="hDataSource" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to my configuration error (of course). I didn't fully grasp that the connection URL was evaluated every time a session was opened against H2 and that means init-h2.sql was executed repeatedly. init-h2.sql included a truncate followed by an insert so it was dropping and recreating data every time Hibernate opened a session.